# No arguments configurable in "Run configurations" (Eclipse Luna)

Tags: c, eclipse

If I open a new C project I cannot set any arguments in the "Run Configuration" settings (same for Debug Configuration). How to solve this ?

I installed Eclipse CDT Version: Luna Service Release 2 (4.4.2) (Build id: 20150219-0600). On Linux Fedora KDE.
[image]

Comment: What kind of project did you create? Is eclipse reporting any errors when opening the config window (look in the Error Log view)?

Comment: I created a C project.

Comment: Log says only:
`!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui.browser 2 0 2015-06-18 19:24:39.873
!MESSAGE Internal browser is not available: No more handles [Browser style SWT.MOZILLA and Java system property org.eclipse.swt.browser.DefaultType=mozilla are not supported with GTK 3 as XULRunner is not ported for GTK 3 yet]`

Comment: Maybe it is worth to mention that I have some color problems with Eclipse. Some fonts are not readable since they have the same color as the background they are written on.

Answer (score 0):

Yet, the only solution I found is to change to *Eclipse Kepler*.

I opened a bug ticket. You will find it  [here](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=470870).